# WP custom featured image size not working if image is smaller than defined crop size?

Tags: php, wordpress, image, function, wordpress-featured-image

I am trying to manually add more featured image sizes in the functions.php, but if the set image size is larger than the image width, the crop is not being created?

```
add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );
add_image_size( 'custom-square', 400, 400, true );
add_image_size( 'custom-medium', 1440, 9999 );
add_image_size( 'custom-large', 1920, 9999 );
```

So if I upload an image with a width of 1000px, the 1440px version is not being created for some reason. How can I correct this?

Comment: WordPress won't scale images up - see [this ticket](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/23713)  According to the comments "Main reason is that it doesn't make really sense since the quality will not be better when upscalling it in the browser."

Comment: There's some code [here](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/wp-351-wp-image-editor-scaling-up-images-does-not-work) that says it'll scale up, though I can't vouch for it (and it may no longer be compatiable with WordPress)

Comment: Ha ! Amazing ! Worked like a charm that scaling script ! Thanks so much !